Ajaxtoolkit:cascadingdropdown - drop down works perfectly in IE but not in other browser in asp.net-C#
I recently joined new company that they are using old asp.net in VS2008 ,.net framework 3.5 and xhtml 1.0 transitional. It is quite old. One of the problem i had during modification that they are using Ajaxtoolkit3.0 cascadingdropdown. Dropdown (ajaxtoolkit) works on IE perfectly but not in other browser. First time, I have to add through IE then it allows other browser to select dropdown.
Error in chrome. exp head group is empty it should show data:

At the same time. please see what IE shows.
IE is showing perfectly result:

First user select from this dropdown
<asp:DropDownList runat="Server" CssClass="frmTextBox" ID="ddlBudgetExpenseHead" Width="600px" />
and then this appear
<asp:DropDownList runat="Server" CssClass="frmTextBox" 
                                                                                        ID="ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail" Width="400px" AutoPostBack="True"
                                                                                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                                                                    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail_CascadingDropDown" Category="BudgetExpenseHead"
                                                                                        ServicePath="~/WebService/wbsBudgetReferenceHead.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetBudgetReferenceHeadDetailListByBudgetExpenseHeadID"
                                                                                        runat="server" Enabled="True" ParentControlID="ddlBudgetExpenseHead" TargetControlID="ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail"
                                                                                        PromptText="All Budget Expense Head Groups(s)" LoadingText="[Loading Budget Expense Head Groups(s)]"
                                                                                        SelectedValue="" />

pageload
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                
                GetValuesFromSession();
                LoadProjectSiteLocation();
                LoadBudgetReferenceHead();
                LoadRequirmentTypes();


              
                LoadUnitOfMeasurementForDuration();
                if (ViewState["IndentID"] != null)
                {
                    LoadIndentInformation();
                    LoadQuerySendTo();
                   
                }

 protected void LoadBudgetReferenceHead()
        {
            SMART.DAL.BMS.BudgetExpenseHead objBudgetExpenseHead = new SMART.DAL.BMS.BudgetExpenseHead();
            ddlBudgetExpenseHead.DataSource = objBudgetExpenseHead.SelectByProjectID(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ProjectID"]));
            ddlBudgetExpenseHead.DataTextField = "BudgetExpenseHeadDescription";
            ddlBudgetExpenseHead.DataValueField = "BudgetExpenseHeadID";
            ddlBudgetExpenseHead.DataBind();
        }

 protected void ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SMART.DAL.BMS.BudgetExpenseHeadDetail objBudgetExpenseHeadDetail = new SMART.DAL.BMS.BudgetExpenseHeadDetail();
            DataTable dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail;

            if (ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.SelectedItem.Value == "")
            {
                dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail = objBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.SelectByID(-1);
            }
            else
            {
                dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail = objBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(ddlBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.SelectedItem.Value));
            }
            if (dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                if (dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.Rows[0]["UnitofMeasurementDescription"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Text = dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.Rows[0]["UnitofMeasurementDescription"].ToString();
                    //ViewState["BudgetUnitofMeasurementDescription"] = dtBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.Rows[0]["UnitofMeasurementDescription"].ToString();

                    if (txtIndentDetailItemUOM.Text == txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Text)
                    {
                        txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = false;
                        lblBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = false;
                        txtConversionFector.Text = "1";
                        txtConversionFector.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = true;
                        lblBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = true;
                        txtConversionFector.Text = "1";
                        txtConversionFector.Visible = true;
                    }

                    //lblBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = true;
                    //txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Text = "";
                    txtConversionFector.Text = "0";

                    txtConversionFector.Visible = false;
                    lblBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = false;
                    txtBudgetUnitofMeasurement.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

Webservice method
[WebMethod]
        public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetBudgetReferenceHeadDetailListByBudgetExpenseHeadID(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
        {
            SMART.DAL.BMS.BudgetExpenseHeadDetail objBudgetExpenseHeadDetail = new SMART.DAL.BMS.BudgetExpenseHeadDetail();

            StringDictionary kv = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);
            Int32 BudgetExpenseHeadID;
            if (!kv.ContainsKey("undefined") ||
            !Int32.TryParse(kv["undefined"],  out BudgetExpenseHeadID))
            {
                return null;
            }

            DataTable dt = objBudgetExpenseHeadDetail.SelectByBudgetExpenseHeadID(BudgetExpenseHeadID);

            //kv["Project"].ToString()
            List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string BudgetReferenceID = dr["BudgetExpenseHeadDetailID"].ToString();
                string BudgetReferenceDescription = dr["BudgetExpenseHeadDetailDescription"].ToString();
                values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(BudgetReferenceDescription, BudgetReferenceID));
            }
            return values.ToArray();
        }

Can you help me what should i do so it will work everytime in all browser? I think i should upgrade ajaxtoolkit so it will solve the problem.
I tried to add some parameter autopostback in first dropdown code and also tried by adding Asyncpostback but nothing work. Now i am thinking to upgrade ajaxtoolkit. maybe after that it will solve my problem. can you please advice me or suggestion to solve this problem?

If you are really sure that your version of the Ajax Toolkit is 3?
Then yes, I would most certainly upgrade the version.
Thankfully, the fine folks at DevExpress maintain that toolkit, and in fact have fixed and added significant upgrades, and that includes HTML5 support.
The latest version is 20.1 or later. So, if you really are on version 3? Well, that appeared when HTML5 I don't think even existed.
Keep in mind that that if you upgrade, then you want to remove the AjaxScriptManager.
You now do NOT require 2 script managers, and the AJ toolkit been changed and upgraded to use the asp.net Script Manager.
This is VERY nice, in that you thus don't want or need or are to use the Ajax Toolkit script manager, which often resulted in 2 script managers existing in a given web page.
So, you need to upgrade that package, and thus support will exist for all modern browsers.
You can download the AJ toolkit from here:
https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit
Or you can even use NuGet.
Since your current version is so very old, then pages using the AJ toolkit will require you to remove the Ajax ToolKit script manager, and you are to now use the asp:ScriptManger in its place. (just drag and drop the asp:ScriptManager from the tool box into the markup where the AJ ScriptManager was being used.
I was introduced to the AJ toolkit more then 10 years ago, and back then, it was version 17, and today it is version 20.
I should also point out that the code is open source, and source code is included in the DevExpress download.
You also not mentioned what version of the .net framework that project is using.
So, you could consider upgrading the .net framework, and even consider using vs2022 for development against that project. If the project is say .net 3.5, then simply changing the project to .net 4.0 should allow it to build, and if it does, then change the project to 4.8.1, and see if that works. But, first step is to upgrade the version of the AjaxToolit to a later version that will correctly support modern browsers. And I recall that the AJ Toolkit dropped support for .net 2.0 framework some years ago.

I am using .Net framework 3.5 and yes i am sure that we are using ajaxcontroltookit 3.0.20820.0 so you are using if i update ajaxtoolkit into the latest version it will works? is it possible that i will maintain both version and i changed only one form not others with the latest one?

If i update then it will effect whole project also? I mean that i have to update whole project with the latest VS also if i update ajaxtoolkit? Right now head of department didn't approved for upgradation of the project

I believe that the new version supports 3.5.  2.0 support was dropped sometime around the last 10 years.  I don't think you need to upgrade VS, but you will have to upgrade the AJ toolkit if you want support for newer browsers.  So, I don't believe that you require a newer version of VS.  As noted, those pages using the older AjaxScriptManager needs to replace that with the standard asp.net script manager. I thus would test this on a copy of the project

sure will do that. Albert D. Kallal
